# HTML5 Alert Box Text Changing Without JS

Tags: html

Hi I have a question from html 5. I want to change the text or other forms' elements' alert when the user enters the wrong inputs.
Oh and I wanna try without the javascript of course
THX

In the Image you see an alert coming from the E-Mail Text Box I want to change its text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thats not an alert but a 'REQUIRED' tag for the HTML form elements

Unfortunately, you cannot set alerts based on wrong inputs using the REQUIRED tag